# Redundant serialization of linked list and pointer into list

Tags: java, pointers, serialization

I have kind of a contrived question.

Let's say I have a linked list of users, and one of these users is "User of the week":

```
public class UserOfTheWeek implements Serializable {
    private UserNode root;
    private UserNode userOfTheWeek;

    //...

    private class UserNode {
        String username;
        UserNode next;
    }

    public void saveToFile() {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ...
        oos.writeObject(root);
        oos.writeObject(userOfTheWeek);
    }
}
```

`root` obviously stores a reference to the head of the list, and `userOfTheWeek` could point to any of the nodes. I want to save the linked list, but will saving the `userOfTheWeek` make a copy of a part of the list? If the user at the head of the list happens to be the user of the week, this could save the entire list twice, and worse, `userOfTheWeek` wouldn't point to an object in the list pointed at by `root`.

Does anyone know what will happen? And if not, I am also open to an alternate solution.

Comment: It will save "part of the list" twice if you do it like that, since there is no way for the separate calls to `oos.writeObject` to know that the other occurs, so both need to save all of the transitively-referenced data. Why not simply `oos.writeObject(this)`? Why make `UserOfTheWeek` `Serializable` if you're not going to use it?

Comment: Because when I load from the file later on, I can't do `this = (UserOfTheWeek) ois.readObject()`

Comment: Well, sure. But you could say `UserOfTheWeek instance = (UserOfTheWeek) ois.readObject();`. That's how you use Java serialization.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought I would end up having to do. I didn't really want to rewrite all my code though... Quick question though: is there some way to do `this = (UserOfTheWeek) ois.readObject()` in the class constructor? That's what I'm trying to do in the first place

Comment: No; you're not invoking the constructor, `ois.readObject()` gives you the instance "already constructed". (Actually, there are methods you can override to do something similar to this... but I get the feeling that you don't really understand Java serialization well enough to really need to use that mechanism).

Comment: Hahaha that would be a good observation. Sadly, this isn't for fun, it's homework, so I'll need to defer actual learning until later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndyTurner You are mistaken. 'There is no way for the separate calls ... to know that the other occurs' is not correct.

Comment: @EJP well, blow me down. A little experimentation has convinced me of the error of my ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to save the linked list, but will saving the userOfTheWeek make a copy of a part of the list?

No.

> If the user at the head of the list happens to be the user of the week, this could save the entire list twice

No.

The stream knows which objects have already been serialized to it, and doesn't reserialize them. See the [Object Serialization Specification #1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4176). Similarly, the object is only deserialized once. Object graphs can be serialized and recovered in full generality, including cycles.

> and worse, userOfTheWeek wouldn't point to an object in the list pointed at by root.

You would have to serialize and deserialize that separately, but it won't result in creation of a new object, it will refer to an object in the list.

Comment: Well, this is very good to know. By the time I noticed this answer I had already implemented Andy Turner's solution, which worked quite well. However, I will be sure to take advantage of this fact next time (it would have saved me some frustration). Thank you for pointing out the specification, which clearly explains what would happen if I had done what I was proposing in the question